# What is setu, Mahasetu and Kulukka?

Tags: mantras, tantra, japa

In [Saraswati Tantra](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/sarasvatItantram.html), I came across three things: **The Kulukka (कुल्लुका), setu (सेतू) and Mahasetu. Although the tantra says that these are body parts of Japa**, the tantra does not address much on what these really are. The Tantra does provide Kulukka of various mantras of many deities. For e.g. The Kulukka of All Taramantras is beej of Nila-sarswati.

Very few sites mention these mantra suggesting that it's not practiced today or practiced but kept secret.

**1. What is setu, Mahasetu and Kulukka exactly, which tantra will provide more info on it?**

**2. Are these three similar to the beej, shakti and keelkam?**

NOTE: Sarswati tantra is not about Godesses Sarswati. It presents the order in which the Matrika are taken up from one chakra to the next. The name sarswati is because she is the upward moving kudalini (The Urdhavamukhi Rupa of Kulkundlini)

Comment: Setu is Om generally. But different Vidyas might have different Setus. Similarly for Mahasetus. I will try to answer.

Comment: The word is Kulukka, adi is etc.

Comment: Sure. (yes its Kulukka, didn't realize it earlier)

Comment: @Rickross I found about setu, if you find something please post an answer.

Comment: You can find a lot about Setu and the others on internet. I already have books which have information about Setu, Mahasetu and Kulukka. Its just that I need to find time to compile those verses by consulting those books.